# Facebook comments on ios app using sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have a website which uses the web(Social) plugin for facebook comments for each post/article on the website.
On my iOS app, the same are presented in a webview. 
The users on the app are logged in with Facebook but I can't find a way to enable them to post comments.
I looked up the OpenGraph documentation but it doesn't say anything about this.

How is it possible to maintain a relation between the facebook object on the web and the app and how do I show the people the option to comment?